# Is it possible to get the detected phone number from an UIWebView object?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Currently, i am doing a project which requires to get the phone number from an UIWebView, is it possible to do that? I can figure out a solution that using Javascript to get the html and then use regular expression to get the phone number. Any other suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am trying to do something similar.

Comment: finally i ended with a way of using reg expression to match the phone number in the content.